# Difference between two SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing an SQL query to select the top 50 values  from a column, then calculate the average of those values.  I have written two queries to accomplish this, but they are giving two different values.  I believe the second one below is the correct one, but I'd like to know what the different is between the two and what the first is actually calculating (if I am in fact correct that the second is right).

First Query:

```
SELECT TOP(50) AVG(COL1) AS COL1_AVG FROM dbo.Table
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT AVG(COL1) FROM (SELECT TOP(50) COL1 FROM dbo.Table) AS COL1_AVG
```

Updated Second Query, with TimeStamp:

```
SELECT AVG(COL1) FROM (SELECT TOP(50) COL1 FROM dbo.Table ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) AS COL1_AVG
```

Comment: Actually neither of them are correct. They both are using TOP but have no order by. That means you have no way of knowing which 50 rows are being included in your average.

Comment: in both example you dont get 50 row, because you dont use GROUP By

Comment: The top 50 averages (but there's only one here), or average of top 50.

Comment: @SeanLange - I believe you are correct here, updated query should be:
    

    SELECT AVG(COL1) FROM (SELECT TOP(50) COL1, TimeStamp FROM dbo.Table ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) AS COL1_AVG

Comment: Would be better to update the question instead of a comment so it is legible. However, your first query is getting the top 50 averages and your second query is getting the average of the first 50 rows. They are NOT the same thing. They should be getting different values and we can't tell which one is correct because only you know what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first query is averaging all rows in `dbo.Table` -- it's taking the `TOP 50` averages, but there's only one value.

The second query is taking the top 50 rows (ordered by nothing in particular), and then averaging them.  The second query is what you want.

Comment: It looks like this is correct in identifying the differences between the two, that makes sense